# Refresh org-agenda org-mode

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

I'm a new user of org-mode and thoroughly enjoying and seeing the benefits it can bring. However, I often want to update my agenda file (it's satisfying). This will read like a 1st world problem, but the only way I've found of refreshing it is by going forward and then backwards in time. Is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried typing "r" (no quotes) in agenda mode? See here for the options you have http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html The orgmode manual is big, but you can search within it by adding site:orgmode.org in your online search.

Comment: Also C-h m in any buffer (including agenda) will show you the keymap (and in the agenda buffer, that will include the "r" key for org-agenda-redo).

Comment: I think over time the preferred metaphors change? I did go through mode help, but missed "org-agenda-redo". My eyes were primed to find "refresh" or "reload". Anyway, `r` it is 